# How to config a multiple prefix ConfigurationProperties with kotlin data class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

A kotlin data class in a library A for config immutable properties (all property set to `val` not `var`):

```
data class Cfg(
  val name: String, 
  ...
)
```

Since spring boot 2.2.0, can use the bellow code to config a single but fixed prefix:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.cfg")
data class Cfg(...)
```

My app depends on the library A, but need to config multiple `Cfg` instance with different prefix, such as `app.cfg1` and `app.cfg2`. And these prefixes is chosen by the app. How?

Comment: Let me see if I get that correct, you want your application to control the prefix of the `@ConfigurationProperties` in a class defined in an external library?

Comment: @MarcosBarbero Any way to register multiple `Cfg` instances as spring  bean with different prefix is acceptable.

Comment: You can declare multiple beans of same time using different naming, I'll write as an answer so you can get some code formatting and stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can declare multiple beans of the same type and define prefixes for it as you need, using the class from your example it would be:

```java
@Configuration
class CfgConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("app.cfg1")
  public Cfg cfg1() {
    return new Cfg();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("app.cfg2")
  public Cfg cfg2() {
    return new Cfg();
  }
}
```

You can add as much as you need and the binding properties will be available for you.

Comment: I know this way. But it's not possible for kotlin data class with immutable property, because no setter for properties and without no argument constructor to instance Cfg class.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of the post! Unfortunately, there's not much you can do to bind this type of class